# Visual Studio 2012 Debugging Custom Object (Class)

Tags: vb.net, debugging, visual-studio-2012

I don't know if this ever happened to any of you.
I am debugging my VS vb.net application and going through the contents of my custom object.

It has several properties and a few ArrayLists.

When I pass the mouse over the first time for an ArrayList i.e:

```
Public Class Class1
    Inherits BaseClass

    Private SourceTIs As New ArrayList()
    Private TargetTIs As New ArrayList()
    Private strID As String
    'Private strImageMap As New String("")

...
```

When I browse through these private properties there is one "TargetTIs" that keeps increasing itself up every time I browse through it.
This sounds crazy, but I don't know how or why... there isn't any other background process or thread that could be increasing the number of items.
the debugger it is stopped in one line, and each time I pass my mouse over it the count increases.

Any help or indication would be appreciated!

Cheers

Comment: "keeps increasing itself up"... do you mean that the number of items in the array is increasing? Please post the entire Class1 code.

Comment: Yes. The number of items gets multiplied x times. I'll try to post some code. But it is happening as my mouse is over the variable name. Weird. Thanks!

Comment: Post the entire Class1 code.

Comment: you might have both the base class and child class manipulating it

Comment: @Plutonix they are private vars... so it must be within the scope of Class1

Comment: No the base class has only a few properties, no logic. What gets me is that I don't understand how even when the debugger is stopped in one line of the code there, just by pointing the variable with the mouse it the arraylist increases by 6. The program should be in stand by until I press "Continue", that's what I thought.